# Smartclient get all listgrid records

Tags: grid, smartclient, listgrid

I am using smartclient. I am having two listgrids that i drag and drop items to a third one. How can i get all records that are on the third one, when i click a button or a certain event is happening. I have tried multiple ways such as loops, default handlers eg. ondrop calculate, but i can not use ondelete or something similar in case a record is removed. I providing a way i tried. This code is from the thrird grid

```
onDrop:function(){
                alert('dropped');
            }
onDropOut:function(){
                alert('removed');
            }
```

the dropout handler doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

if you want all the records when dropping on the third one

```
onRecordDrop:  function(dropRecords, targetRecord, index, sourceWidget){
  this.data; // this are all the records in the list grid
}
```

now if you want on any event, imagine the third listgrid id = "thirdgrid"

```
someevent: function(){
  thirdgrid.data; //this are the records of the third grid;
}
```